# Integrating over discontinuities

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, periodic-functions

I have the following integral:

\begin{align}
\int^T_0e^\tau I(\tau+t^0)d\tau.
\end{align}

In this integral, $I(t)$ is a function with period $T$.  At each time $T, 2T, \ldots$, $I$ is increased by a constant $K$.  The starting value of $I$ is such that $I$ decreases by $K$ between the moments of these instantaneous increases.

The definition of $I$ is

\begin{align}
I(t) = \tilde{K}e^{-t/\tau_0},
\end{align}

where $0\leq t<T$, $\tilde{K}=\frac{K}{1-e^{-T/\tau_0}}$, and $I(t)=I(t+iT)$ for all integers $i$.

In the integral, $t^0$ can be negative, zero, or positive.  When $t^0=0$, evaluating the integral is easy.

But when $t^0$ is negative or positive, the integral crosses discontinuities of the function $I$.

How should I handle this?

### Note

Ignoring the periodicity, one could rearrange the integral to be

\begin{align}
I(t^0)\int^T_0e^{\tau(1-1/\tau_0)}d\tau
\end{align}

and solve that.  I don't have much intuition for whether that's legitimate with regard to the periodicity, but my impression is that it's not -- mainly because when I compute the integral this way, my results (using specific values for all the constants) don't match the results in the paper I'm trying to replicate.

So my secondary question is, is this rearrangement of the integral legitimate, and why or why not?

Comment: Your discontinuity is finite, and the Riemann integral can handle it well. For any integrand bounded over $[a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]$, $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x)dx \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. 

In your case, split the integral as

$$\int_0^T f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{T-t_0} f(t +t_0) \mathrm{d}t + \int_{T - t_0}^T f(t + t_0) \mathrm{d}t$$ 

$f(t + t_0)$ is easy to find over each of these domains.

Comment: Yeah, the integral on the LHS should be over $f(t + t_0)$ as well. My bad.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 working through it, i don't see a way to solve for $t^0$ analytically.  do you?

Comment: added a more exact method as an answer that should clarify. You're **not** solving for $t_0$, that's a given constant.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 i mean, i **am** solving for $t^0$.  it's not a given constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $t_0 = kT + \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in [0, T), k \in \mathbb{Z}$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^T \tilde{K} e^\tau I(\tau + t_0) \mathrm{d}\tau \overset{(a)}= \int_0^{T} \tilde{K}e^\tau I(\tau + \alpha) \mathrm{d}\tau \\
= ~& \int_0^{T-\alpha} \tilde{K} e^\tau I(\tau + \alpha) \mathrm{d}\tau + \int_{T-\alpha}^T \tilde{K} e^\tau I(\tau + \alpha) \mathrm{d}\tau \\
\overset{(b)}= ~& \int_\alpha^{T} \tilde{K} e^{\tau_1 - \alpha} I(\tau_1) \mathrm{d}\tau_1 + \int_{0}^\alpha \tilde{K} e^{\tau' - \alpha + T }I(\tau' ) \mathrm{d}\tau' \\
\end{align}

Where $(a)$ follows from $I(t + KT) = I(t)$, and $(b)$ is the following substitutions:

1. $\tau_1 = \tau + \alpha$ in the first integral
2. $\tau' = \tau + \alpha - T$ in the second integral.

Now you know $I$ over each of the required intervals, as they all lie within the first period. Integrate away.

Comment: cool, thanks.  unless i'm missing something, though, this seems redundant with your first two comments, and i find your first two comments easier to digest and apply.  that said, i like having an answer posted (as opposed to just comments) so i'm accepting.